# Binance::API: can't connect to the exchange

Tags: perl, binance

I'm an algo-trader and Perl fan.
I want to create a client which connects to Binance Future Testnet and i decided to exploit the Binance API module developed for Perl.

Once the [Binance::API](https://metacpan.org/pod/Binance::API) module was installed (no errors or warnings occurred there) i dived into my script first lines of code as follows:

```
#!/bin/perl 

use Binance::API;

#API di Binance-Testnet
my $api = Binance::API->new(
    apiKey    => 'my api',
    secretKey => 'my secret key',
);
 
$api->account(); 
$api->exchange_info();
```

API KEY and SECRET KEY are taken from my Binance Future Testnet Account (freely available for all users), succesfully used via tradingview and its Pine script tool.

Unfortunatly i got the following error:

```
[Binance::API::Request::_exec] Unsuccessful request.
Status => 401,
Content => {"code":-2015,"msg":"Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action."} at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Binance/API/Request.pm line 107.
[Binance::API::Request::_exec] Unsuccessful request.
Status => 404,
Content => <html><body><h2>404 Not found</h2></body></html> at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Binance/API/Request.pm line 107.
```

Any idea on what went wrong with this? I don't want to use Python or C++ as I love Perl and its versatility.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at Binance::API source code, you can see this module developed for Spot market. not Futures.
https://github.com/taskula/binance-perl-api/blob/master/lib/Binance/Constants.pm

```
BEGIN {
%constants = (
    BASE_URL => $ENV{BINANCE_API_BASE_URL} || 'https://api.binance.com', #this endpoint is for spot
    DEBUG    => $ENV{BINANCE_API_DEBUG}    || 0,
);
}
```

for Spot Testnet you can get API KEY from here:
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#enabling-accounts

Comment: i see your point. That's what i suspected since the beginning but, changing the endpoint in the aforementioned module from 'https://api.binance.com' to 'https://testnet.binancefuture.com' and running the script i got the same error reported in my first post! I also dived into the module 'Request.pm' which uses the 'Constant.pm' one but i didn't find anything suspicious therein. The whole matter sounds strange to me, above all if you consider that there're some proprietary bridges (es.TV-HUB) which easily implement Binance-Futures and Binance-Futures-Testnet API.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may get confused with spot and futures. There are 4 different base URL for different markets:

1. Spot Production site: `https://api.binance.com`
2. Spot Testnet site:  `https://testnet.binance.vision`
3. Futures Production site: `https://fapi.binance.com`
4. Futures Testnet site: `https://testnet.binancefuture.com`